# How To get Sum of two fields from databse

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT agent_id, SUM(amount) FROM bill WHERE YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY agent_id"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total ". $row['agent_id']. " = $". $row['SUM(amount)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

DB Structure image:

[image: Database structure]

What I want know how is it possible to display sum of cheque and amount currently its working as sum of amount only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure can, your query would just look like this:

```
SELECT agent_id, SUM(amount + cheque) 
FROM bill 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY agent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this (what i understand from your question)--

```
SELECT agent_id, (SUM(amount)+sum(cheque)) As total FROM bill WHERE YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY agent_id";
```

Comment: Yea Both Are Working Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT agent_id, (SUM(amount) + SUM(cheque)) AS total_amount
FROM bill WHERE YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY agent_id
```